# two-part fastener for right-angle wood connections

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture, fastener, materials

I have some furniture which is missing a screw/nut pair used for fastening two pieces of wood together at a right angle. The screw is 45mm long and 5mm wide, and it's paired with some kind of nut with a threaded hole in the side of its cylinder shape instead of through the center of the faces. The nut and the screw are placed into two separate pieces of wood at right angles, and fastening the screw pulls the on the nut and fastens the two pieces of wood together. Here's a picture of one of the screw/nut pairs I still have:

[image: black screw with mated right-angle bolt]

Can anyone tell me what this hardware is called? I need to track down a replacement set.

Comment: I am looking for you. It is a type of low socket cap screw and barrel fastener commonly seen in furniture. Can't swear Home Depot carries them (largest stores only) but will track it down. Often i have to go to the manufacturer to get replacements. Do you know the brand name or where you got the furniture?

Comment: You'll need to verify the thread pattern. If it's metric, you'll need to check Fastenal and other specialty hardware stores as well as the manufacturer. The big boxes dont carry much metric.

Comment: What country are you in? I'm fairly sure that I have some of these in the shed, rescued from an old bed.

Comment: If it is metric (very likely if you outside the US) these are pretty standardised and can be picked up online fairly easily. If you are buying them as a set rather than just the bolt or nut alone, you probably don't even need to worry about the diameter too much, just the length.

Comment: Ikea mainly use M6, but this might be M5 by the sound of things.

Comment: @SiHa I'm in the UK, same as you, but I could also come up with a handful from the Ikea etc. fixings tin.

Comment: I live in Germany, and the furniture in question is this high chair: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B00KWZPSS2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question! These aree common on DIY furniture.

It's a [cross-dowel and bolt](https://www.rockler.com/cross-dowels). One commercial name is a [Veritas Knock-Down Fastener](https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/fasteners/knockdown-hardware/67659-veritas-knock-down-fasteners). A similar device, with a head to keep it level with a surface, is the [barrel nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_nut).

If you search on "cross dowel" at hardware stores such as [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/s/cross%2520dowel?NCNI-5) or at  [Lowes.com](https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=cross%20bolt), you should find a part to fit.

Comment: Amazon has furniture barrel screw sets - metric or imperial.  I bought a bunch of sets as I always seem to loose one somehow.  Ebay sometimes has good deals from china if you can wait a few months.

Comment: They may also be found as "bed (or bedframe) bolts"

Comment: Thanks so much! Ended up going with these: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/JPGhaha-Galvanised-hexagon-cylinder-furniture/dp/B08T8ZNTLM. I'll use a hacksaw to shorten the screws, and the rest of the dimensions match exactly.